# JavaDB - autoincrement among several tables

Tags: java, sql, derby, javadb

Is it possible to have autoincrementing id among several tables? 
What I mean exactly - I have (let's say five) tables, one of them is a table containing information about sales (sale_id, sold_item_id) and another four contain info about different kind of sold stuff. I want these four to share one pool of ids. How do I do that?

Edit.
I decided to choose Juxhin solution and I created additional table. Everytime I create a record in one of these 4 tables, I autoincrement new id in that additional table and this id is in one of columns of that new row.

Comment: Alot of other factors take place, you could just have a Data class and store current ID there and increment of that value

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the use case for a [sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/) and the link seems to indicate that javadb supports this.

So you create one common sequence for all tables:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MASEQUENCE
```

and then use it when inserting into your tables:

```
 INSERT INTO TAB1(ID,....) VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR MYSEQUENCE,...)
```

Each `NEXT VALUE` will advance the sequence and so all ids will be unique across all tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new record to be inserted into all 5 tables when you insert something into one of them, then you can create a trigger for this.

It may also be helpful to create foreign keys on the id columns in the other tables (to keep the tables in sync).

Comment: I wanted the new record to be inserted into one table, but make sure that auto increment would give it an id from the common pool. Nevermind anymore, I picked Juxhin solution.